# background images not being called on html when using stylesheet

Tags: html, css, image, background

Hello everyone I have a quick question. I am learning about HTML and CSS using Visual Studio 2012. I am trying to have multiple backgrounds to try a parallax effect type of thing. I know CSS can have multiple backgrounds like so:

```
    background: url("/file/image.png"), url("/file/images2,png"), etc.....
```

But what I am trying to do is call the images using the div id selector like so

```
    #image1 { background:url ("/file/image.png");}


    #image2 { background: url ("/file/image2.png");}
```

HTML

```
    <body>

    <div id="image1"></div>
    <div id="image2"></div>
```

Every time I run the following code I don't have anything showing on screen. The only time I get something is if I put the code on the body{ }. Am I missing something or is VS 2012 not set up properly?

Thanks

Comment: i think you missed the "following code"

Comment: When using an external stylesheet the path to the images is relative to the CSS file, not the HTML page that links to it. Are you sure that the path is correct, and do the background images show up in the resources of the page (using your browser's web-developer tools)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the height and width of the image in your css style

```
#image1 { background:url ("/file/image.png"); height: xxxpx; width: xxxpx;}
#image2 { background: url ("/file/image2.png"); height: xxxpx; width: xxxpx;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `div` tag by default is a height of the content within it. If you have no content in the `div` then it will be a height of zero. You may need to manually add the height of the images to the div tags:

```
div#image1 { height: 200px; /* Height of image.png */ }
div#image2 { height: 300px; /* Height of image2.png */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not Visual Studio. If you're using background images without anything contained within them, then there's no content for your div elements to size to.

You either need to set fixed dimensions on your div elements or put enough content within them so that they size appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you just need to double-check the *location* of your images.

In the line:

```
#image1 { background:url ("/file/image.png");}
```

In CSS, url is relative to the location of this stylesheet. In Visual Studio 2012, if your .css file is in a folder and your images are in another "file" folder on the same level, you'd write it as:

```
#image1 { background:url ("../file/image.png");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all the quick replies. All the answers regarding the width and height worked on my code and the image was able to display fine.

Thanks.